# Unexpected directive 'DataTable' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on a simple angular 2 project, I have all my imports within my app.module.ts as below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StockListComponent } from './stock-list/stock-list.component';

import { routing } from "./app-routing.module";
import { StockItemComponent } from './stock-item/stock-item.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { DeviceConfigurationComponent } from './device-configuration/device-configuration.component';
import { StockStatusComponent } from './stock-status/stock-status.component';


import {Calendar, Dialog, Button, InputSwitch, Dropdown, Growl, DataTable, SelectButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {JwtHelper, AuthHttp, tokenNotExpired} from "angular2-jwt";

import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {DataService} from './data.service';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  StockListComponent,
  StockItemComponent,
  ProfileComponent,
  DeviceConfigurationComponent,
  StockStatusComponent
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  routing,
  DataTable,
  Calendar,
  Dialog,
  Button,
  InputSwitch,
  Dropdown,
  Growl,
  JwtHelper,
  AuthHttp,
  SelectButtonModule
 ],
 providers: [
  AuthService,
  DataService
 ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I do not any errors in my terminal window, however, in chrome's console window i get the following error.

```
metadata_resolver.js:227Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'DataTable' imported by the module 'AppModule'(…)
(anonymous function) @metadata_resolver.js:227
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @metadata_resolver.js:212
RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @runtime_compiler.js:130
RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @runtime_compiler.js:68
RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @runtime_compiler.js:59
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @application_ref.js:302
PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ application_ref.js:284
(anonymous function) @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap fbc4961…:52
(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1327
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap fbc4961…:52
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap fbc4961…:23
```

(anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js:1

Comment: What version of `primeng` are you using?  It looks like they updated from the old `DataTable` to the newer module pattern: `DataTableModule`

Comment: But im getting the same error with AuthHttp jwt import

Answer (score 0):

probably too late and, you've already figured it out, but regarding AuthHttp, it shouldn't be imported, but instead provided, take a look at angular2-jwt Basic configuration: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [{
        provide: AuthHttp,
        useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
        deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }]
})
```